# Swift - How to save data to Firebase from multiply selected cells in TableView?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, tableview, cell

I need to save all data from selected cells in tableView to Firebase Database.
In cells I have just labels, no buttons, actions or textfields. I want when I select multiply cells, then click to saveButton and all data from cells to store on Firebase.

Comment: It should be relatively simple to use the didSelectRowAt and keep track of every index called in a separate array, then use that array as a reference to pull data from your table view's main datasource and send it to Firebase.  Have you tried that?

Comment: @SuperTully no, I haven't try that. I'm new in swift and I do this first time.

Comment: Ok, see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a look at Apples documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/handling_row_selection_in_a_table_view), you will see a section that discusses how to properly handle multiple row selections.

Like I said in my comment though, you will need to use the

```
tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

method, and inside that function append the indexPath.row value to an array you can reference outside of that function call (so you can set it up as a instance property of your view controller, for example).  Once all desired rows have been selected, when the user clicks the send button, you can loop through the index array, then pull the necessary record from your data source and upload it to Firebase, or you can populate a temporary array and send the whole array to Firebase, whatever works best for you.

Here's a simple example of what I mean

```
var indexArray: [Int] = []

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  
   indexArray.append(indexPath.row)
   
}

func sendToFirebase() {
 for index in indexArray {
  //... get record from datasource and send to Firebase
 }
}
```

Make sure you take a look at Apple's documentation though, because it discusses deselecting the rows and using check marks as best practice for displaying selected rows.

Comment: This helps me to learn about cells, but I want to ask how to record from datasource? Till now I haven't meet whit datasource. This is my first app.

Comment: @AnDon - Your data source is what your cells pull data from when they display onscreen.  So, if your cell labels contain the names of movies for example, you could use an Array (of String type) that contains movie names, then you use the indexPath to in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method to pull the right data from that array object.